# Custom templates for a specific category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, templates

I am having issues creating a custom page template for a category in WP. I am currently using the standard content type "post".

So the issue is I have a parent category, and many sub categories and I would like any posts within these categories to use a specific layout. This custom template should apply to all sub categories within the parent. Is this possible, or would I need to create separate templates for each sub category?

I have looked at custom post types as another option, but It doesn't seem they have the hierarchy options required.

Any advise would be appreciated

Comment: You could use the `template_include` hook for Posts, or look further into CPTs - what hierarchy are you trying to achieve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114934/make-wordpress-subcategories-use-category-template#answer-46750921

Comment: Thanks, I may look deeper into CPTs, I did try the option to use the existing categories from core WP, but it seemed to flatten them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this [article](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) in the [the WordPress Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/).

You should create a template in your theme named `category-unicorns.php` where **`unicorns`** is the **slug for the parent category** you want this template to be used for.
You can also create a template file `category-5.php` where **`5`** is the **id of the parent category**.